# Slicer is got getting filtered

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have sales table.

I have created slicer on sales region. This shows all sales region options.

Then I added 2 table visual with sales region and sales amount. Anothet table with sales region and count of workers.

Selecting any item from slicer filters both the table. Selecting a region in any table filters the other table.

However, selecting the region in table dows not filter the slicer. Is this by design or can it be controlled so filter passes from table into slicer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit interaction from Format tab in the ribbon. From there you can define the interaction between each visuals.

For more details, you can visit [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/service-reports-visual-interactions)

========================

I think I got your concern now. Please check the quoted text I got by googling-

> You can filter all visuals in Power BI except Slicer! In fact slicer itself is a type of filter, however there are some times that number of items in slicer is too many. So this is normal that we want to filter the items in the slicer itself. Unfortunately current version of Power BI Desktop doesn’t support visual level filter on slicer.

To me, it's a logical functionality or behavior or interaction between different visual and slicer. Otherwise if slicer got filtered itself by selection values in a table or other visuals, in some case it will produce circular dependency.

Comment: So for slicers it is by default turned off. Where as for other visuals by default it is turned on?

Comment: The edit interactions filter/disable has no impact on the slicer values. Please can you check and let me know.

Comment: Can you show some sample data and a screenshot of your presentation?

Comment: It's just 1 sales table with sales id, region and amount

Comment: Hi @variable, I have added some more details on how a slicer works in power bi. hope this will help you understanding the scenario.

Comment: For other visuals, when I click on edit interactions I can click on filter or disable icon. Any idea what those mean?

Comment: You can control interaction between 1) Slicer to visuals (single direction) 2) Visual to Visual (both direction) by them.

Comment: Does the filter or highlight require that there should be a relation/filter direction in the data model? For example I have sales fact. And m:1 relation on product_id to product dimension. To analyse (example sum or avg) by product category (category is column in product table) do I need to separate the category in its own table or is it ok to be in product table?

Comment: Table relation and direction is important for data filtering.

Comment: Can you help me with this - say I have transaction (acct_id,t_amt) and account (acct_id, acct_name). M:1 relation from transaction to account table. I have 3 table visual. 1: transaction.acct_id, transaction.t_amt; 2: account.acct_id, account.act_name; 3: account.acct_name, transaction.t_amt. Selecting acct_id in transaction visual (1) does not filter 3 but filters 2. Why is this.

Comment: Can you prepare a sample report with sample data? Provide me the report after that and I will check then.